# How to change from localhost to localhost.local in wamp?

Tags: facebook, cakephp, wamp

I'm using cakephp 2.1 and WAMP for one of my app which is making use of Facebook Connect plugin. Getting an error saying

> An error occurred. Please try later

Googled and found this

```
http://ardentdev.com/no-facebook-connect-cookies-for-localhost-development/
```

But not coming to know how to chance the settings from localhost to localhost.local for app in WAMP.

Comment: tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

Comment: Try setting the debug level to 1 or 2 and check your error.log and debug.log files under app/tmp/logs to get started on the debugging process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add a virtual host. To do this, edit the apache configuration file that came with WAMP. This is assuming you're on OSX.

**/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/conf/http.conf**

```
# add the following
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/project" 
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, edit your hosts file. Open up the terminal, and run the following (use whatever editor you like, I'm choosing Vi):

`$ sudo vi /private/etc/hosts`

And add a host to point to our new site.

`127.0.0.1 mysite.local`

Lastly, restart the WAMP server and you should be able to visit `mysite.local` in your browser and it will point to your project.